# Powerpoint Keyboard Shortcut to "Save as Picture..." for selected item

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint

I use ppt all the time to make quick images for export as png, jpg, etc... To export, I right-click on the object and choose "Save as Picture..." This avoids the layers of menus File-->Export-->etc...

My question is, how can I make a keyboard shortcut that will do the same thing as right clicking on an object and choosing "Save as Picture..."? (**A**)

If it is not possible, can I make a macro and assign a keyboard shortcut to that? If so, any pointers?

Here's what I've tried so far:
Using System Setting --> keyboard --> with several different key combinations (to avoid conflicts), but that didn't work (**B**) and I could not find "Save as Picture..." among the Ribbon/Quick Access Toolbar customization commands (**C**).

[image]

Comment: Acorrding to [Keyboard shortcuts in PowerPoint for Mac](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-in-powerpoint-for-mac-f25f92b3-b0a8-4c60-aec8-954b72aa81ad), there is no such shortcut to Save as Picture. It also applies to PowerPoint for Windows.